# MySQL SELECT id + SELECT * WHERE id IN (...) seems faster than plain SELECT *. Why?

Tags: mysql, database, performance, select, where-clause

I am running the following query over a view called `shipments_last_twenty_days`:

*Q1*:

```
SELECT shipments_last_twenty_days.* FROM shipments_last_twenty_days 
LEFT JOIN customers ON shipments_last_twenty_days.customer_id = customers.id 
WHERE customers.store_id = 147;
```

A workmate noticed that the query would spend almost all its processing time doing 'Sending Data' and also that this time fluctuated a lot, and he suggested that I **split the query into two parts, the first one to retrieve just the ids and the second one to retrieve all the fields using the ids** (unless there are no ids returned in the first step, which happens around 80% of the time). He said **this might work faster**, and based on some tests today I think he was right by about a factor of two. The problem is, **I don't understand why**. Here are the two queries I divided the original query into:

*Q1a* (and `EXPLAIN` output):

```
SELECT shipments_last_twenty_days.id FROM shipments_last_twenty_days 
LEFT JOIN customers ON shipments_last_twenty_days.customer_id = customers.id 
WHERE customers.store_id = 147;

+----+-------------+-----------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+-----------------------+-------+-------------+
| id | select_type |   table   |  type  | possible_keys |   key   | key_len |          ref          | rows  |    Extra    |
+----+-------------+-----------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+-----------------------+-------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | shipments | range  | date          | date    |       9 |                       | 61758 | Using where |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | customers | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY |       4 | customers.customer_id |     1 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-----------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+-----------------------+-------+-------------+
```

*Q1b* (and `EXPLAIN` output):

```
SELECT * FROM shipments_last_twenty_days WHERE id IN (2668955, 2671554);

+----+-------------+-----------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+-----+------+-------------+
| id | select_type |   table   | type  | possible_keys |   key   | key_len | ref | rows |    Extra    |
+----+-------------+-----------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+-----+------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | shipments | range | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY |       4 |     |    2 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-----------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+-----+------+-------------+
```

...(where 2668955 and 2671554 are obviously the values returned by *Q1a*).

Can anyone explain to me why this is? If the difference is based on the 80% of times that *Q1b* is not executed because *Q1a* returns no results...shouldn't *Q1a* (`SELECT id`) be just as costly as *Q1* (`SELECT *`) if there is nothing to return?

PS: I didn't add index information or table information because I figure this result should be independent from that, but please do ask if necessary. Also, the MySQL version is 5.1 (I know it's old).

**EDIT (additional info):**

`SHOW CREATE VIEW shipments_last_twenty_days;`

```
CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER=`fakeuser`@`0.0.0.0` 
SQL SECURITY DEFINER VIEW `shipments_last_twenty_days` AS 
select `shipments`.`id` AS `id`,
`shipments`.`prog` AS `prog`,
`shipments`.`customer_id` AS `customer_id`,
`shipments`.`id_corriere` AS `id_corriere`,
`shipments`.`id_destinatario` AS `id_destinatario`,
`shipments`.`id_servizio` AS `id_servizio`,
`shipments`.`id_servizioLDV` AS `id_servizioLDV`,
`shipments`.`id_fattura` AS `id_fattura`,
`shipments`.`id_abbonamento` AS `id_abbonamento`,
`shipments`.`date` AS `date`,
`shipments`.`dataMod` AS `dataMod`,
`shipments`.`dataDel` AS `dataDel`,
`shipments`.`dataCreazioneAWB` AS `dataCreazioneAWB`,
`shipments`.`dataTrackPartenza` AS `dataTrackPartenza`,
`shipments`.`dataTrackConsegna` AS `dataTrackConsegna`,
`shipments`.`hasLDV` AS `hasLDV`,
`shipments`.`nColli` AS `nColli`,
`shipments`.`Contenuto` AS `Contenuto`,
`shipments`.`peso` AS `peso`,
`shipments`.`pesoLDV` AS `pesoLDV`,
`shipments`.`isDocumento` AS `isDocumento`,
`shipments`.`isTrasportoPreziosi` AS `isTrasportoPreziosi`,
`shipments`.`isMerceDaImballare` AS `isMerceDaImballare`,
`shipments`.`isReturn` AS `isReturn`,
`shipments`.`prezzoCalcolato` AS `prezzoCalcolato`,
`shipments`.`prezzoFinale` AS `prezzoFinale`,
`shipments`.`notes` AS `notes`,
`shipments`.`isFatto` AS `isFatto`,
`shipments`.`fatturaImporto` AS `fatturaImporto`,
`shipments`.`fatturaAssicurazione` AS `fatturaAssicurazione`,
`shipments`.`fatturaContrassegno` AS `fatturaContrassegno`,
`shipments`.`isFatturato` AS `isFatturato`,
`shipments`.`isAnnullato` AS `isAnnullato`,
`shipments`.`isModificatoAmministratore` AS `isModificatoAmministratore`,
`shipments`.`valoreContrassegno` AS `valoreContrassegno`,
`shipments`.`valoreAssicurazione` AS `valoreAssicurazione`,
`shipments`.`valoreMerce` AS `valoreMerce`,
`shipments`.`shipmentValueCurrency` AS `shipmentValueCurrency`,
`shipments`.`isConsegnatoTracking` AS `isConsegnatoTracking`,
`shipments`.`failedDelivery` AS `failedDelivery`,
`shipments`.`bookingNumber` AS `bookingNumber`,
`shipments`.`riferimentoMittente` AS `riferimentoMittente`,
`shipments`.`masterTrk` AS `masterTrk`,
`shipments`.`isPagamentoDaziAlMittente` AS `isPagamentoDaziAlMittente`,
`shipments`.`isEsportato` AS `isEsportato`,
`shipments`.`labelMasterExtension` AS `labelMasterExtension`,
`shipments`.`contrassegnoTipo` AS `contrassegnoTipo`,
`shipments`.`isNotificaInternaInviata` AS `isNotificaInternaInviata`,
`shipments`.`trackDataPartenza` AS `trackDataPartenza`,
`shipments`.`trackDataConsegna` AS `trackDataConsegna`,
`shipments`.`trackFirmaConsegna` AS `trackFirmaConsegna`,
`shipments`.`trackDataSalvataggio` AS `trackDataSalvataggio`,
`shipments`.`isCreatoDaWebService` AS `isCreatoDaWebService`,
`shipments`.`shipmentOrigin` AS `shipmentOrigin`,
`shipments`.`boxdropId` AS `boxdropId`,
`shipments`.`isControllataFatturaFornitore` AS `isControllataFatturaFornitore`,
`shipments`.`noteConsegna` AS `noteConsegna`,
`shipments`.`webServiceTipo` AS `webServiceTipo`,
`shipments`.`isTrackDatiConsegnaManuali` AS `isTrackDatiConsegnaManuali`,
`shipments`.`numeroChiusura` AS `numeroChiusura`,
`shipments`.`dataChiusura` AS `dataChiusura`,
`shipments`.`corriere` AS `corriere`,
`shipments`.`isChiusoManifestSDA` AS `isChiusoManifestSDA`,
`shipments`.`costoAcquisto` AS `costoAcquisto`,
`shipments`.`isConsegnaSabato` AS `isConsegnaSabato`,
`shipments`.`isPortoAssegnato` AS `isPortoAssegnato`,
`shipments`.`portoAssegnato_codice` AS `portoAssegnato_codice`,
`shipments`.`portoAssegnato_codice_cap` AS `portoAssegnato_codice_cap`,
`shipments`.`pagamentoDazi_codice` AS `pagamentoDazi_codice`,
`shipments`.`pagamentoDazi_cap` AS `pagamentoDazi_cap`,
`shipments`.`isChiusoBorderoSGT` AS `isChiusoBorderoSGT`,
`shipments`.`isRichiestaImport` AS `isRichiestaImport`,
`shipments`.`idDepartment` AS `idDepartment`,
`shipments`.`use_dpd_predict` AS `use_dpd_predict`,
`shipments`.`dpd_predict_channel` AS `dpd_predict_channel`,
`shipments`.`dpd_predict_value` AS `dpd_predict_value`,
`shipments`.`dpd_predict_language` AS `dpd_predict_language`,
`shipments`.`UPSSignatureRequired` AS `UPSSignatureRequired`,
`shipments`.`returnRecipientOption` AS `returnRecipientOption`,
`shipments`.`returnRecipientDepartmentId` AS `returnRecipientDepartmentId`,
`shipments`.`returnOptionUPS` AS `returnOptionUPS`,
`shipments`.`exportedToManifest` AS `exportedToManifest`,
`shipments`.`shipmentSource` AS `shipmentSource`,
`shipments`.`valueMBESafeValue` AS `valueMBESafeValue`,
`shipments`.`goodsDescriptionMBESafeValue` AS `goodsDescriptionMBESafeValue`,
`shipments`.`NEXShippingCollectionId` AS `NEXShippingCollectionId`,
`shipments`.`NEXShippingId` AS `NEXShippingId`,
`shipments`.`serviceAfterDowngrade` AS `serviceAfterDowngrade`,
`shipments`.`UPSAdultSignatureRequired` AS `UPSAdultSignatureRequired`,
`shipments`.`addressUPSAccessPoint` AS `addressUPSAccessPoint` 
from `shipments` 
where ((`shipments`.`date` >= '2020-04-18 00:00:00') and 
(`shipments`.`date` < '2020-05-09 00:00:00') and 
(`shipments`.`isAnnullato` = 0) and 
(`shipments`.`hasLDV` is true) and 
(`shipments`.`isEsportato` is false))
```

`SHOW INDEX FROM shipments`

```
+-----------+------------+----------------------+--------------+-----------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
|   Table   | Non_unique |       Key_name       | Seq_in_index |   Column_name   | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment |
+-----------+------------+----------------------+--------------+-----------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
| shipments |          0 | PRIMARY              |            1 | id              | A         |     2636401 |          |        |      | BTREE      |         |
| shipments |          1 | MittentiOrdini       |            1 | id_destinatario | A         |     2636401 |          |        | YES  | BTREE      |         |
| shipments |          1 | masterTrk            |            1 | masterTrk       | A         |     2636401 |          |        | YES  | BTREE      |         |
| shipments |          1 | prog                 |            1 | prog            | A         |      376628 |          |        | YES  | BTREE      |         |
| shipments |          1 | customer_id_and_date |            1 | customer_id     | A         |       32548 |          |        | YES  | BTREE      |         |
| shipments |          1 | customer_id_and_date |            2 | date            | A         |     2636401 |          |        | YES  | BTREE      |         |
| shipments |          1 | date                 |            1 | date            | A         |     2636401 |          |        | YES  | BTREE      |         |
+-----------+------------+----------------------+--------------+-----------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
```

PS: I am aware that MySQL doesn't seem to be using the composite index I created for this query. I will try running it without the view, and then I think MySQL will use it (the view was a performance improvement when I didn't have that index). Anyway, for the purpose of this post, what interests me most is why *Q1a* + *Q1b* could be faster than *Q1*, I want to understand that (if it makes no sense from a theoretical point of view, please just tell me, maybe my tests were wrong).

Comment: "Sending data" does not provide any actionable info; ignore that clue.  Don't say `LEFT` when it is not.  Please provide `SHOW CREATE VIEW`.

Comment: Also, note that queries against views in MySQL cannot access underlying indexes, rendering views (in my view) almost useless.

Comment: And if you execute EXPLAIN EXTENDED followed by SHOW WARNINGS, you will see that there is no LEFT JOIN here, as RJ says.

Comment: @RickJames Ok, I posted the definition of the view and the indexes in the underlying table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this index to `shipments`:

```
INDEX(isAnnullato, hasLDV, isExportato, customer_id, date, id)
```

If any of those columns are `TEXT` or `BLOB`, then consider removing them from the `VIEW`.

**Split up a query?**

Almost always, splitting up a complex query into two simpler queries will be slower.  Think of it this way:  There is overhead for each query -- network, parsing, designing the query plan, sending data back.  For a "simple" query, 90% of the query cost is this overhead.

**What to include in an `INDEX`**

It depends.  There are many criteria, so it is hard to state any rule that 'always' works.  Here are some that 'usually' work for a 'composite' (multi-column) index:

- It will be better than individual (single-column) index(es).
- The order of the columns *in the index* usually matters.
- Boolean values are fine in a composite index.
- Put things tested with `=` first.  The order (in the index) does not matter.
- At most one range at the end.
- Even after doing the above, consider making a "covering" index by tacking on any other columns mentioned anywhere in the query.
- Don't have more than 5 columns.  (Yes, I violated that in my suggestion.)
- An index *may* help selects/deletes/updates.
- An index slows down inserts -- but usually the benefit to the other queries far outweighs the cost to the inserts.
- `UPDATEing` a column that is in an `INDEX` is somewhat costly -- the index entry must be deleted and a new one inserted.

More discussion: http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql

**Analyzing the suggested index**

```
INDEX(isAnnullato, hasLDV, isExportato,  -- first because of "="; any order
      customer_id,   -- I'm not sure where to put this
      date,          -- range
      id)            -- for "covering"
```

Comment: Ok, thank you. I was planning next to try an index with all or most of the columns in the query but I hadn't yet because 1) those extra ones are booleans so I wasn't sure how much of an effect it would have and 2) I don't know exactly how costly it is to maintain an index. Anyway, I'll test this

Comment: Regarding my original question, do you know whether it makes sense that Q1a + Q1b could be faster than Q1? From a theoretical point of view, does that sound possible?

Comment: @javier - see if my modifications address your concerns.  Removing even on boolean from my index would prevent it from getting to `date`, thereby destroying the main goal -- to limit the query to 20 days.